# Was sind die genauen Regeln zur Benutzung des Buchstabens "ſ"?

Tags: blackletter

Im Fraktursatz gibt es zwei Arten des Buchstabens "s": "s" (das runde s) und "ſ" (das lange s). Das ß ist im Fraktursatz eine Ligatur aus ſ und z. (Also ß = ſz). Im Gegensatz zum Englischen wird dieses im Deutschen nach semantischen anstatt graphischen Regeln gesetzt.

Im Duden stehen Regeln für die neue Rechtschreibung. (Die im Übrigen etwas merkwürdig sind, so wird z. B. das "dass" "daſs" geschrieben...) Aber welche Regeln gelten für die alte Rechtschreibung?

Comment: Die Frage ist nicht so recht sinnvoll: das lange ſ ist eine *typografische* Konvention, die es zudem nur in der Fraktur gibt. Mit Sprache hat das nichts zu tun (auch wenn, wie Du korrekt bemerkt hast, semantische Regeln über den Satz bestimmt haben), und da Fraktur nicht mehr üblich ist, ist auch das lange ſ ausgestorben.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Lt. Duden gibt es Regeln zur Benutzung des langen s (Ich habe nur eine 26. Auflage, daher nur für neue Rechtschreibung). Es ist somit nicht nur Konvention sondern auch den Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung unterworfen.

Comment: Auf jeden Fall kommt man als Deutscher auch gut zurecht, wenn man diese typografische Variante nicht anwendet.

Comment: @user unknown Dem muss ich entgegentreten. Jede Sprache (und jede Form der Rechtschreibung) hat eigene, möglicherweise andere Regeln für die Setzung des ſ, die Trennung von Ligaturen und weiteren typographischen Konventionen im Fraktursatz. Ich möchte wissen, inwiefern es Unterschiede zwischen alter und neuer Rechtschreibung gibt.

Comment: @userunknown Die Frage ob man s oder ſ setzt ist je nach Sprache und Rechtschreibung eine typographische (Englisch) oder semantische (Deutsch). Da sich einige Semantiken (z.B. Silbentrennung) mit der Rechtschreibreform geändert haben, ist es schon wichtig, die Rechtschreibreform zu betrachten.

Comment: @user unknown: Das ist schlichtweg falsch: Das lange ſ kann für jedes Phonem stehen, für das heute ein s genutzt wird. Lediglich das runde s kann nicht für einige Phoneme stehen, was aber eher Nebenprodukt als Wesen der Regeln ist. Mehr dazu [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/hatten-das-runde-s-und-das-lange-die-gleiche-aussprache).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Was genau ist denn schlichtweg falsch? Das die englische Orthographie das ſ nach typographischen Gesichtspunkten setzt oder das die deutsche Rechtschreibung semantische (hier: Von der Silbentrennung abhängige) Schreibung verwendet? Ich habe nie etwas über Aussprache gesagt.

Comment: @Hellenologophilist: Mein letzter Kommentar richtete sich nicht an Dich, sondern bezog sich auf den letzten Kommentar von user unknown.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Entschuldigung. Ich habe mich anscheinend verlsene.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft und Hellenologophilist: Dann habe ich die Regeln zum ſ komplett missverstanden. Es geht also gar nicht um die Aussprache. Ein Glück sind wir den Galgen los! :) Ich lösche dann mal meine falschen Kommentare.

Comment: [Eine ziemlich ausführliche historische Aufdröselung des Themas](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/246689/Pictures/Herbert%20E.%20Brekle%20-%20Gebrauchsregeln%20lang-s%20und%20rund-s.pdf), leider auch ohne knappe, funktionierende Regeln.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In den Regeln der [Orthographischen Konferenz von 1901](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographische_Konferenz_von_1901) zur Schreibung der S-Laute steht folgendes:

> 1. **ſ** steht außer zur Bezeichnung des weichen S-Lautes ferner ohne Rücksicht auf die Aussprache
>
>    - im Anlaut der Nachsilben -sel, -sal, -sam.
>    - im Inlaut nach Mitlauten.
>    - vor einem zur Stammsilbe gehörigen **p** und **t** sowohl im Anlaut [...], als auch im Inlaut und Auslaut.
> 2. **ſz** steht zur Bezeichnung des harten S-Lautes
>
>    - im Inlaut nur nach langem Selbstlaut.
>    - im Auslaut aller Stammsilben, die im Inlaut mit **ſz** oder **ſſ** zu schreiben sind.
> 3. **ſſ**, die Bezeichnung für den doppelten harten S-Laut, steht nur im Inlaut zwischen zwei Selbstlauten, von denen der erste kurz und betont ist.
> 4. **s** steht nur im Auslaut, und zwar
>
>    - aller Stammsilben, die im Inlaut mit ſ geschrieben werden. [...] Jedoch bleibt das inlautende **ſ** vor einem **t** der Biegung.
>    - aller Endungen, auch der Nachsilbe **-nis**.
>    - solcher Wörter, die vor einer mit einem Selbstlaut beginnenden Nachsilbe nicht vorkommen.[...] Man unterscheidet **das** als Geschlechts- und Fürwort und **daß** als Bindewort.
>    - in Zusammensetzungen.
>
> **In lateinischer Schrift steht s für ſ und s, ss für ſſ, ß für ſz; für ß tritt in großer Schrift sz ein.**

[Hier online ein Faksimile der Originalregeln](http://archive.org/stream/Regeln-fuer-die-deutsche-Rechtschreibung/RegelnFuerDieDeutscheRechtschreibungNebstWoerterverzeichnis190832Doppels.ScanFraktur#page/n5/mode/2up) inklusive der oben gekürzten Beispiele und in Fraktur gesetzt.

Bereits 1901 ist also festgehalten, dass das lange 'ſ' nur im Fraktursatz verwendet wird und in der lateinischen Schrift nicht vorkommt.

Comment: Das Problem ist, dass diese Regeln viele Fremdworte nicht abdecken oder für sie falsche Ergebnisse liefern. Ein paar Beispiele aus der Wortliste der verlinkten Regeln: Maske (rundes s im Inlaut), Diſziplin (langes s als scharfes s im Inlaut nach Selbstlaut, ohne das p oder t folgen), Disput (rundes s als scharfes s im Inlaut nach Selbstlaut, gefolgt von p), Pſalm (scharfes s im Anlaut).

Answer (score 8):

Schon vor der letzten Rechtschreibreform war das lange s nur noch im Fraktursatz vorgesehen (siehe [Deutsche Rechtschreibung im 19. Jahrhundert](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Rechtschreibung_im_19._Jahrhundert)).

Die allermeisten Fälle lassen sich mit den folgenden Regeln abdecken:

1. Das runde s steht am Ende sinntragender Einheiten von Wortbestandteilen, wie Wörtern oder Vorsilben, sofern sie nicht verbunden mit dem nachfolgenden Wortbestandteil gesprochen werden (wie z. B. in *Leſung).*
2. Das runde s steht zudem im Silbenauslaut, wenn es weder Bestandteil eines Polygraphen (z. B. ſch oder ſſ) ist noch der folgende Buchstabe p, t oder z ist.
3. In allen anderen Fällen steht das lange s.
4. Auslassung eines tonlosen e haben keine Auswirkung auf die s-Schreibung (z. B. in *unſre = unſere).*

In ein paar Fällen ist es jedoch nötig, die genaue Etymologie des Wortes o. Ä. zu kennen, um über die s-Schreibung zu entscheiden, wie z. B. bei *Aſbeſt* (von *α-σβεστος).*

Ausführliche Beispiele finden sich unter anderem im [Wikipedia-Artikel „Langes s“](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langes_s#Regeln_zur_Verwendung_von_langem_.C5.BF_und_rundem_s) oder [bei Typographie.info](http://www.typografie.info/3/page/FAQ.htm/_/wie-setzt-man-das-lange-s-im-klassischen-fraktursatz-r12).

Comment: Dann sag mir mal bitte, warum der Duden in der 26. Auflage immernoch Regeln zum korrekten Gebrauch von langem und kurzem s enthällt, wenn diese doch schon längst abgeschafft worden sind? Im Fraktursatz (Und darauf bezieht sich meine Frage) hast du gar keine andere Möglichkeit, als ſ und s zu unterscheiden.

Comment: Mh. Mir war nicht klar, dass sich die Rechtschreibung mit der Typographie ändert. Sind die Regeln in dem Wikipedia Artikel denn die, nach denen du suchst?

Comment: “Es wird nur dann verwendet, wenn es in Eigennamen vorkommt” – mir ist kein Eigenname bekannt, in dem ein langes ſ vorkommt – hast Du ein Beispiel?

Comment: Es scheint wirklich selten. [Dieses Bild](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Fuersteneck_Kirschwasser.jpg) taucht im Wikipedia Artikel auf; Ich würde wetten, die meisten jener Eigennamen sind Marken– oder Personennamen (und nicht unbedingt die, lebender Personen).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Es gibt tatsächlich einen recht berühmten Mann, der ein langes s im Namen hat(te): Herr Litfaſs, der Erfinder der gleichnamigen Säule.

Comment: Das mit den Eigennamen ist nicht richtig: Ob ſ/s oder ausschießlich s verwendet wird, hängt nur davon ab, ob gebrochene Schriften oder Antiqua benutzt werden. Früher, v. a. in der Frühzeit des Buchdrucks, benutzte man ſ auch im Antiquasatz und hin und wieder tut man das immer noch, etwa um einen gestalterischen Effekt zu erzielen (wie im Bild) oder um ältere Texte buchstabengetreu wiederzugeben. In jeder Quellenangabe heißt es "Vierteljahreshefte für Zeitgeschichte", z. B. [hier](http://www.ifz-muenchen.de/heftarchiv.html).

Answer (score 3):

Das **Zeichen** (von einem "Buchstaben" zu sprechen ist nicht korrekt) wird meines Wissens im modernen Deutsch der letzten Jahrzehnte **nicht mehr verwendet**.

Es wird nicht in Schulen gelehrt. Weiters ist das Zeichen auf handelsüblichen Computertastaturen nicht aufgedruckt.

Nach den verbindlichen [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) von 2006 ist das lange 'ſ' **kein gültiger Buchstabe**. Eventuelle Regeln sind allenfalls historisch zu betrachten.

Comment: Zumindest unter Linux: [AltGr] [s] ergibt ſ.

Comment: Das [Neo-Tastaturlayout](http://www.neo-layout.org/) enthält auch das lange s.

Comment: Computertastaturen unterstützen alle und kein Zeichen gleich. Sie senden einen Tastaturcode, und Software entscheidet dann, wie dieser zu interpretieren ist. Die aufgedruckten Zeichen bedeuten gar nichts.

Comment: @userunknown Haarspalterei. Ich schrieb "*direkt* unterstützen" (wie zum Beispiel das *ß*). Dass das Zeichen im modernen Deutsch verschwunden ist, ist doch eine Tatsache. Deswegen verstehe ich die drei Downvotes zu diesem Detail nicht. Da ändert auch nichts daran, wenn 0,001% der Bevölkerung ein spezielles Tastaturlayout verwendet.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Votes auch nicht. Das "ſ" gibt es einfach nicht mehr. Weg. Und mit ihm sind auch alle Regeln verschwunden.

Comment: Die Verstimmung könnte daher rühren, dass in der Frage explizit nach den Regeln der alten Rechtschreibung gefragt wurde.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Okay, stimmt. Darauf bin ich in der Antwort nicht eingegangen. Ich wollte in meiner Antwort Menschen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen, erklären, dass die Rolle des Zeichens z. B. nicht den Stellenwert des "ß" hat.

Comment: (At) splattne: Das Zeichen ist so direkt oder indirekt zu erreichen wie ein @ oder ein €. Dass `direkt unterstützen` bedeutet, dass man kein AltGr dafür braucht müsste man schon dazu sagen. @Hellenologophilists Kommentar, dass es mit <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> erzeugbar ist, und das hab ich ausprobiert, und es hat auf Anhieb funktioniert - ohne Installation oder Änderung von Systemeinstellungen. So habe ich `direkt` verstanden. Wenn ich ein zeitgenössisches Buch bestelle, und bekäme eins mit ſ-en, würde ich es reklamieren - da gebe ich Dir recht. Nichtdestotrotz ist die Antwort off topic.

Comment: In Windows ist es eben **nicht** direkt, also einfach zu erreichen. Die Eingabe von Alt+383, wie im Wikipedia-Artikel (St. Palazzos Antwort) zu lesen,  ist erstens nicht intuitiv und _funktioniert nicht in jedem Programm_! Hier mit Firefox kann ich das zum Beispiel nicht ins Kommentarfeld eingeben.

Answer (score 1):

Das runde s wird am Silben- / Wortende benutzt. Sonst schreibt man das lange s.

Also z.B. Haus mit rundem s und Gaſthof mit langem s.

Comment: Also das ist zu dem Griechischen Sigma (σ,ς) ähnlich.

Comment: Das ς wird ausschließlich am Wortende verwendet.

Comment: Dass das runde s genau am Silbenende auftaucht, liest man zwar häufiger, ist aber falsch. Das lange s kann ebenfalls am Silbenende stehen, und zwar wenn ein ſ, t, p oder z folgt (laſſen, laſten, raſpeln, Diſziplin). In seltenen Fällen kann das runde s auch vor dem Ende der Silbe stehen, z. B. in *grotesk.*