# Hatten das runde „s“ und das lange „ſ“ die gleiche Aussprache?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Gab es einen Unterschied in der Aussprache von rundem „s“ und langem „ſ“, oder war der Unterschied nur typographisch?

[image: das alles paſſieren muſʒte.]

Comment: Das lange s ist übrigens kein besonderes deutsches Phänomen, sondern wurde in so gut wie allen Ländern und für Texte aller Sprachen (die mit dem lateinischen Alphabet geschrieben wurden) verwendet.

Comment: Das "ſ" wird zwar wie das "s" ausgesprochen, aber das ungewohnte Schriftbild lässt es mich zuerst immer als "f" lesen - so, als ob der Text massiv gelispelt würde. Ich lese deshalb immer zuerst "das alles paffieren musste".

Comment: nd01: same over here... a friend of mine used to write: "Wenn ich Fraktur lefe, muff ich im Geifte lifpeln"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dadurch, dass das runde s nur am Auslaut vorkommt, gilt natürlich die Auslautverhärtung, weswegen man es gewöhnlich nicht als /z/ sprechen konnte, sondern immer nur /s/. Genauso wenig ist (standardsprachlich) die Aussprache als /ʃ/ möglich, da Kombinationen /ʃt/ und /ʃp/ nicht über Wortgrenzen (u. Ä.) gesprochen werden.

Für das lange s lässt sich eine derartige Einschränkung nicht treffen, da es sowohl im An- als auch im Auslaut auftreten konnte. Es kann also als /z/ (ſacht), /s/ (luſtig) oder /ʃ/ (ſteil) ausgesprochen werden. Ebenso kann das lange s Bestandteil eines Digraphen sein, z. B. ſch (ausgesprochen als /ʃ/, z. B. in *raſch)* oder ſſ (ausgesprochen als \s\, z. B. in *laſſen).*

Das runde s wird also im Grunde so ausgesprochen wie ss und ß.

Generell gilt, dass das lange s nicht anders ausgesprochen wird als ein rundes s an derselben Stelle, *ſyſtematiſch* spricht sich also genau so wie *systematisch.*

Comment: Zu ergänzen ist, dass in Österreich alle s (ſ, s, ß, samt Verdoppelungen) gleich ausgesprochen wurden und größtenteils auch heute noch gleich ausgesprochen werden, nämlich stimmlos (also als [s]). Das stimmhafte s ([z]) kommt in der österreichischen Aussprache nicht vor. Ausgenommen ist natürlich das s vor p, t und ch, das als [ʃ] gesprochen wird: *Speck, Stein, Schal*). Da seit einigen Jahrzehnten das deutsche Deutsch einen sehr großen Einfluss auf das österreichische Deutsch hat, gibt es aber auch in Österreich bereits einige (vor allem junge) Sprecher, die ein stimmhaftes s ([z]) verwenden.

Answer (score 11):

Laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langes_s) ist "ſ" eine typografische Variante von "s", hat also nur eine andere schriftliche Erscheinungsform, aber **keine andere Aussprache**.

[Weiter unten im Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langes_s#Verwendung) gibt es allerdings Hinweise, wie "ſ" manche Doppeldeutigkeiten in der Schriftform von Komposita (und damit einhergehend auch unterschiedliche Aussprachen gleich geschriebener Wörter) vermeiden kann - diese Eigenschaft ist mit dem "ſ" verloren gegangen:

> [...] Daher
>   kann die Differenzierung zwischen ſ
>   und s für den Leser von besonderem
>   Vorteil sein. Beispiel: Durch
>   Verwendung des langen ſ ist es auch
>   ohne Kontext sofort klar, ob eine
>   Wachſtube (Wach-Stube) oder eine
>   Wachstube (Wachs-Tube) gemeint ist.
>   Weitere Beispiele: Kreiſchen
>   (Krei-schen, für Schreien) oder
>   Kreischen (Kreis-chen, für kleiner
>   Kreis), Verſendung (Ver-sendung) oder
>   Versendung (Vers-Endung), Röschenhof
>   (Rös-chen-hof, von kleine Rose) oder
>   Röſchenhof (Rö-schen-hof, vom
>   Eigennamen Rösch).

Comment: +1 für RÖSCHENHOF!!!! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDj0prlOfB0

Comment: bei Rostock gibt's einen Ort namens Häschendorf. Die Bewohner haben bestimmt viel zu erzählen ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Von der Aussprache her waren die beiden Formen wohl schon immer identisch. Jans Hinweis auf die einfachere Differenzierung von mehrdeutigen Wörtern (die man natürlich auch anders lösen kann) kann ich zustimmen. Interessant ist dazu der Grimm, der unter ["S", I. 5.](http://dwb.uni-trier.de/Projekte/WBB2009/DWB/displayLinkInfo?lemid=GS00001) folgendes erwähnt:

> schreib- und druckschrift brauchen für s zwei zeichen, ein langes für an- und inlaut, und ein rundes (schlusz-s) für den auslaut eines wortes oder einer silbe. die sogenannte lateinische oder rundschrift hat indes seit den ersten jahrzehnten dieses jahrhunderts, unter dem einflusz der französischen und englischen druckereien angefangen, das lange s zu gunsten des runden zu beseitigen; jetzt ist dieses runde s an jeglicher stelle des wortes so eingebürgert, dasz versuche, das alte verhältnis wieder herzustellen, völlig gescheitert sind. auch für den doppellaut und die ligatur sz (vgl. oben 4) setzt ein weitverbreiteter gebrauch in der rundschrift ss, wogegen in einer minderzahl von schriften ss und sz, die auflösung der ligatur, nach den regeln der heutigen rechtschreibung unterschieden angewendet werden.

Unter dem referenzierten Abschnitt 4 wird (auf ein oder zwei Seiten, daher zitiere ich jetzt mal nicht) auf den Ausspracheunterschied und Schreibunterschiede zwischen ss, sz und ʒ eingangen. Ein interessanter Auszug dazu:

> diesen laut bezeichnete die alte schrift schwankend und vielfach ungenau [...] - der heutige in fachschriften durchgeführte zeichenunterschied zwischen z = tz und ʒ für den s-ähnlichen laut rührt erst von J. Grimm her.

Die beiden Schreibweisen für s werden jedoch nicht als unterschiedlich ausgesprochen beschrieben.

Comment: Stimme zu, man kann diese Differenzierung auch anders lösen - heutzutage bleibt einem auch gar nichts anderes übrig :-) Der Nutzen war ja eh nur bei denjenigen Komposita vorhanden, bei denen an der Wortgrenze ein "s" steht...