# Wörter mit ungünstiger Silbentrennung

Tags: curiosity, hyphenation

Gibt es noch andere Beispiele außer das klassische Wort "Urinstinkt", bei denen eine an und für sich korrekte Silbentrennung einen falschen Sinn suggeriert?

Comment: In deinem Fall also Ur-instinkt vs. Urin-stinkt.

Comment: @mbx: "Hände Waschen nach dem Pinkeln ist ein Urinstinkt, weil Urin stinkt."

Comment: Ich habe den Eindruck, dass sowohl Close-Voter wie auch manche Antwortende die Idee haben, dass es hier um den Unterhaltungswert geht. Es ist aber bei einem Wort wie Urinstinkt tatsächlich wichtig, dieses Phänomen in einem professionellen Kontext zu vermeiden, für die meisten angegebenen Beispiel ist das nicht der Fall.

Comment: Es ist eine Umfrage, das steht in der Hilfe.

Answer (score 24):

Da gäbe es beispielsweise:

- Urinsekten
- Streikende
- Arbeit-Samt
- Wachstube
- Erblasser
- Staubecken
- Versendung
- Eistempel
- Gründung
- Müllerzeugung
- Musikerleben
- Spielende
- Torflaute
- Teilerfolge
- Barkasse
- Erbrecht (danke @Jan)

Wobei, wenn dein Beispiel geht, geht natürlich auch:

- Duschlampe

Als Klassiker gäbe es außerdem:

- Die viel gefeierten Blumento-Pferde

Ich habe mir jetzt mal die Erklärung der jeweils zweiten Bedeutung gespart, das macht es möglicherweise amüsanter.

Comment: Gestatten, Oli Venöl.

Comment: Als Mitsprecher der Deutschen Sprache staune ich in Anbetracht deiner Liste nicht schlecht über meine eigene Unzulänglichkeit,

z.B. wäre ich vollkommen unfähig "Wachstube" zu entziffern.

Comment: @iceteea: Ja, deshalb gibt es ja auch Leute, [die gerne das lange ſ wieder hätten](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/hatten-das-runde-s-und-das-lange-die-gleiche-aussprache/1404#1404) :)

Comment: *Arbeitsamt, Wachstube, Erblasser, Staubecken, Versendung, Eistempel, Torflaute, Erbrecht* und *Blumentopferde* genügen nicht den Anforderungen der Frage, da ein Missverständnis nur bei inkorrekter Silbentrennung und nicht bei korrekter zustandekommen kann (genauso wie bei *Duschlampe)* Bei *Urinstinkt* hingegen kann eine korrekte Silbentrennung ungünstig sein, daher ist es nicht mit *Duschlampe* vergleichbar.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: *Streikende* und *Spielende* ebensowenig. Leider überwiegen die unpassenden Antworten damit deutlich gegenüber den angebrachten.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: *Streiken-de* und *Spielen-de* sind korrekte Trennungen des Endes eines Streiks bzw. Spiels. Sie entsprechen damit den Anforderungen der Frage schon deutlich eher als die von mir gelisteten Wörter. (Es sind zugegebenermaßen nicht die schönsten und prägnantesten Beispiele, aber darum geht es ja nicht.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ok, bei den beiden Wörtern sind die Verben durch die Trennung natürlich trotzdem suggeriert, womit *Streikende* und *Spielende* wohl Grenzfälle sind - ich denke, die Frage zielt aber vor allem auf die Wörter ab, die durch eine ungeschickte, aber korrekte Trennung in zwei vollständige Wörter unterteilt werden, welche eine falsche Bedeutung nahelegen (wie es bei den von dir aufgezählten Wörtern eben nicht der Fall ist).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ich widerspreche deiner Behauptung, das Missverständnis käme nur bei inkorrekter Trennung zustande. Beispiel »Eistempel«: Mancherorts werden im Winter prachtvolle Eistempel (Tempel aus Eis) errichtet: http://www.hicker.de/data/media/25/quebec-eishotel_6094.jpg und wo anders zeigt der Eistempel (ein Stempel auf einem Ei) das Ablaufdatum des Eis an: http://www.kirchenweb.at/osterhase/aufdruckaufeier/eeee.jpg Im ersten Fall wäre **Eis-tem-pel** die korrekte Silbentrennung, im anderen **Ei-stem-pel**. Keine der beiden Varianten ist inkorrekt. Dasselbe gilt alle anderen Beispiele.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Okay, »Missverständnis nur bei inkorrekter Silbentrennung« ist nicht ganz korrekt. Natürlich können Missverständnisse immer passieren, aber in besagten Fällen werden sie nicht durch eine korrekte Silbentrennung begünstigt – was gerade die Voraussetzung der Frage war.

Comment: Die problematischen Wörter in dieser Antwort zeichnen sich dadurch aus, das die Silbentrennung die Bedeutung klarifiziert - Wach-stube und Wachs-tube werden nicht verwechselt werden, und Wachstu-be ist nicht verwirrender als Wachstube. Das Problem mit Ur-in-stinkt ist, dass es *leichter* zu verwechseln ist wenn die Trennung als Urin-stinkt geschieht, und Ur-instinkt ist eigentlich nicht klarer als Urinstinkt, denn das Wort ist eindeutig.

Comment: Wer meint, das "Urin-stinkt" eine korrekte Silbentrennung (bzw. korrekte Schreibung mit Bindestrich) wäre, sollte mal die Trennungsregeln rekapitulieren

Comment: @tofro: Laut dem [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Instinkt) darf "Instinkt" sowohl vor als auch nach dem 's' getrennt werden, wobei die Trennung vor dem 's' (also diejenige, die in "Urinstinkt" zu Verwirrung führen kann) sogar die vom Duden empfohlene Variante darstellt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das habe ich nicht gemeint. Urin-stinkt ist keine korrekte Schreibung eines Wortes mit Bindestrich. Und genau darin liegt ja die Missverständlichkeit.

Comment: @tofro: Die Missverständlichkeit liegt darin, dass "Urinstinkt" per Silbentrennung so über zwei aufeinanderfolgende Zeilen verteilt werden kann, dass in einer "Urin-" und in der darauffolgenden "stinkt" steht, was wie zwei vollwertige Wörter erscheint, die aber gar nicht den eigentlichen Bestandteilen des Gesamtworts entsprechen.

Comment: Man kann es kaum noch anders lesen, wenn man das Wort "Posteingang" mal als "Po-stein-gang" gelesen hat :-/

Answer (score 14):

Im Duden *Die deutsche Rechtschreibung* rot unterlegt:

Analphabet

> Das Wort *Analphabet* und seine Ableitungen sollten nicht zwischen *l* und *p* getrennt werden, da sonst eine irritierende und das Lesen hemmende Trennung entsteht.

beinhalten

> Das Wort *beinhalten* sollte nicht zwischen *n* und *h* getrennt werden, da sonst eine irritierende und das Lesen hemmende Trennung entsteht.

Frustration

> Das Wort *Frustration* und seine Ableitungen sollten nicht zwischen *t* und *r* getrennt werden, da sonst eine irritierende und das Lesen hemmende Trennung entsteht.

Sprecherziehung

> Das Wort *Sprecherziehung* sollte nicht zwischen *r* und *z* getrennt werden, da sonst eine irritierende und das Lesen hemmende Trennung entsteht.

Urinstinkt

> Das Wort *Urinstinkt* sollte nicht zwischen *n* und *s* getrennt werden, da sonst eine irritierende und das Lesen hemmende Trennung entsteht.

Answer (score 12):

- Abt-reibung - Ab-treibung
- Alpeno-strand - Alpen-ostrand
- Alter-steilzeit - Alters-teilzeit
- Anal-phabeten - An-alphabeten
- Anschlag-sorte - Anschlags-orte
- Arbeit-samt - Arbeits-amt
- Aussen-dung - Aus-sendung
- Autoren-nen - Auto-rennen
- Billi-greise - Billig-reise
- bein-halten - be-inhalten
- Disco-unterpreise - Discounter-preise
- Dudel-ei - Dude-lei
- Eid-otter - Ei-dotter
- Eil-eiter - Ei-leiter
- Einkauf-stempel - Einkaufs-tempel
- Ei-stempel - Eis-tempel
- Er-blasser - Erb-lasser
- Er-dachse - Erd-achse
- erd-rückend - er-drückend
- Fank-reise - Fan-kreise
- Gas-traum - Gast-raum
- Gaul-eiter - Gau-leiter
- Gel-ächter - Ge-läch-ter
- Gel-brand - Gelb-rand
- Grün-dung - Gründ-ung
- Hau-saufgabe - Haus-aufgabe
- Heimatsch-lager - Heimat-schlager
- Host-essen - Hos-tessen
- Kau-fladen - Kauf-laden
- Kir-schwein - Kirsch-wein
- Musik-erleben - Musiker-leben
- Musi-knoten - Musik-noten
- Müller-zeugung - Müll-erzeugung
- Nach-truhe - Nacht-ruhe
- Nachteil-zug - Nacht-eilzug
- Pan-amazone - Panama-zone
- Paten-trichter - Patent-richter
- Punk-trichter - Punkt-richter
- Rind-erdung - Rinder-dung
- Schweinigel-ei - Schwein-ige-lei
- Sieb-ente - Sie-bente
- Spargel-der - Spar-gelder
- Spieler-öffnung - Spiel-eröffnung
- Staat-sex-amen - Staats-examen
- Staub-ecken - Stau-becken
- Tal-entförderung - Talent-förderung
- Talent-wässerung - Tal-entwässerung
- Talg-rund - Tal-grund
- Tang-ente - Tan-gente
- Tee-nager - Teen-ager
- Teiler-folge - Teil-erfolge
- Textil-lustration - Text-illustration
- Torf-laute - Tor-flaute
- Urin-stinkt - Ur-instinkt
- Verand-abrüstung - Veranda-brüstung
- Wachs-tube - Wach-stube
- Wasserschi-eber - Wasser-schieber
- Zuck-erguss - Zucker-guss
- Zwergel-stern - Zwerg-elstern

In den folgenden Beispielen kommt es zu einem Wechsel der Groß-/Kleinschreibung, was aber z.B. am Beginn eines Satzes nicht auffällt:

- Abt-rennen - ab-trennen
- Anzug-leichen - anzu-gleichen
- Erb-recht - er-brecht
- Erst-unken - er-stun-ken
- Verb-eulen - ver-beulen
- Vers-ehen - ver-sehen
- Vers-unken - ver-sunken

Comment: Aber ist es nicht so, das z.B. *Analphabeten* in Wirklichkeit an verschiedenen stellen getrennt werden kann: *An-al-pha-be-ten* (hoffe, das war richtig) und dass man einfach die Trennung nimmt, die im Satz passt (also was gerade noch im Text passt), also *Analpha-beten* auch vorkommen kann? Ich muss zugeben, dass ich das einfach aus dem Niederländischen übernommen habe, aber vermute, dass es da keine großen Unterschiede gibt.

Answer (score 10):

Ferner gibt es noch das Verb

- be-inhalten vs. bein-halten

(durfte ich in letzter Zeit wieder öfter lesen ...)

Comment: Darüber stolpere ich in Texten mit schlechtem oder nicht existentem Kerning immer wieder

Answer (score 7):

Mir ist heute der Lese-Fehler 'tatun-beteiligt' passiert. Habe 'tatun' tatsächlich gegoogelt, der Groschen fiel sehr langsam. *grins*

Comment: Ähnlich bei Dom-orgel / Domor-gel und be-nebelt / bene-belt.

Answer (score 4):

Beruflich begegnet mir bei automatischer Silbentrennung immer wieder:

Dampf-erzeuger – Dampfer-zeuger

Answer (score 4):

Alt-Bau-Charme versus Alt-Bauch-Arme

Answer (score 4):

Neulich im Warteraum einer Augenklinik lass ich auf dem Info-Monitor:
"MAKULADEGENERATION". Nachkriegs-Generation, Null-Bock-Generation etc. kenne ich so ungefähr. Doch wer oder was ist die Makulade-Generation? Nach einigen gefallenen Groschen haben mich alle Augenärzte schmunzelnd aufklären können. Aber auch nur die.
Obwohl ich stolzer Erfinder eines (laschen) Augenarztwitzes bin, kann ich weiterhin am Stammtisch nicht punkten; schade.

Answer (score 3):

dem-entsprechend vs dement-sprechend

Answer (score 0):

Von Otto Waalkes gibt es ein Gedicht in dem er eine banale Story erzählt und dabei Bergnamen verwendet. Das einzige was ich mir gemerkt habe ist:

> Ein Arzt wollte die Pyre nähen.
>   (Also in Bezug auf die Pyrenäen.)

Comment: Bitte neue Fragen nicht als Antwort einordnen - Du kannst deine Frage getrennt von dieser stellen.

Comment: @tofro: Liest sich für mich wie eine (unvollständige & ungenaue [Was ist eine Pyre?]) Antwort, nicht wie eine Frage. Semi Traweychi: wie ist es gemeint?

Answer (score 0):

Habe ich in der vergnügsamen Auflistung die berühmten Tomaten aus der Au übersehen? Diese netten Sprach-Früchte gibt es in Geldau, in Kondomau usw. und seit Neuestem auch in Maskenau

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Bitte überdenken die Antwort mehr wie eine Antwort aussehen zu lassen: welches Wort genau ist gemeint und aufzeigen wie es bei der Silbentrennung zu Missverständnissen kommen kann. (heißt auch: "die netten Sprach-Früchte" sind mir unbekannt)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Au-tomaten statt Auto-maten, Geldau-tomaten statt Geld-automaten usw. Stimme aber zu, ergibt sich nicht unbedingt auf den ersten Blick, für eine Antwort vielleicht nicht optimal. Obwohl auf den zweiten Blick interessant geschrieben!

Answer (score -1):

üngünstiger und Silbentrennung können selbst an ebenderselben leiden:
ungüns-Tiger und silb-ent-rennung! :-)

Comment: Was ist ein ungüns oder ein silb? In der Frage ging es um Wörter, die trotz **korrekter** Silbentrennung einen anderen, aber gültigen, Sinn implizieren.

Answer (score -3):

Gerne schaut man auch auf die Aufschrift der Wasserflasche;

Bele-bend oder Be-lebend ;)

Comment: Hallo Marcel, willkommen bei German StackExchange! Ich muss gestehen, weder *bele* noch *bend* sind mir bekannt, deshalb sehe ich da das mögliche Missverständnis nicht (außer, dass die Trennung nicht schön anzusehen ist).