# Associativity and splitting of three compound names

Tags: compound, mathematics

Pre-question (answered [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/w%C3%B6rter-mit-ung%C3%BCnstiger-silbentrennung)): Is there a compound word *A|B* with original components *A* and *B* that might be slit as *A'|B'* if *A* borrows some letters from *B* (or the other way around) to form *A'*, and *B'* keeps the rest?

With that background:

Is there a word with three components *A|B|C* such that diverse associativity interpretations could lead to alternative meanings? Like *(A|B)|C* being different from *A|(B|C) ?* Or reorganizing 
*A'|B'|C'* by creating new words with order and letter conservation?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I get what you want: Are you asking for something like _Ur|Instinkt_  <> _Urin|stinkt_?

Comment: Yes, it is only proper German with a space in between, but I needed an example (even if it not fully matches). Would the components A, B, A' and B' need to be valid words when they are not used within the compound words? And are there limitations to their word classes?

Comment: Would _Ei|dotter_ <> _EId|otter_ be a better example? I found it in Hubert's answer to [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/w%C3%B6rter-mit-ung%C3%BCnstiger-silbentrennung) question.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Yes, I was thinking of A,B,A' and B' having to be all valid words (or A' and A prefixes and or B or B' sufixes). No limitation of word classes, I just find that in Scrabble those words should count twice :D I see my question is a dupe, thanks for the info.

Comment: I think, technically it's not a dupe, because you've asked in English. Plus, I can not really see a good 3-compound case in the other answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for a word with 3 components:

> Die Fenster**heberzeit** (die Zeit, die der Heber für eine vollständige
>   Öffnung oder Schließung benötigt) liegt bei diesem Fahrzeug bei gerade
>   einmal 1,2 Sekunden.
>
> Wer kurbelt denn heute noch, wir leben doch längst in einer **Fensterheber**zeit!

Comment: Herrlich, dass es so was gibt. Kann ich fragen, wie du auf die Idee gekommen bist?

Comment: @c.p.: Ich habe gedanklich aus dem Fenster auf die Straße geschaut. Gesehen habe ich parkende Autos.

Answer (score 3):

A classical example for such a word is *Staubecken* which can be read as Stau-becken (from *stauen* and *Becken*) or Staub-ecken (from *Staub* and *Ecke*).

However, the two possibilites differ in number, as the former is singular and the latter is plural.

Comment: I think this should be replaced in our minds with *Frustration*. Much better example.

Comment: @Janka _Frust-Ration_ and what else? I cannot see something like _Fru-Stration_

Comment: Frus-tra-tion und Frust-ra-tion.

Comment: But Frus-tra-tion is not a compound.