# Ambiguous Compound Words

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

In German, different words can combine to form longer, more descriptive compound words. Are there any German compound words that have an ambiguous meaning?

A possibility I've thought of:

If "__" is a word (e.g. "Braut"), "sch__" is a word (e.g. "Schaufel"), and "ch__" is one as well (in this case "Chaufel"), __sch__(Brautschaufel) could be interpreted as "(__s)ch__" ((Brauts)chaufel) or "__(sch__)" (Braut(schaufel)).

I couldn't come up with any examples of this kind of word in German, though.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, hard to understand what you are asking. Do you think you can rearrange your question, maybe with some table style? I guess that is not what you are looking for: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50005/how-does-the-german-superpower-of-word-chaining-really-work ?

Comment: [This question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1705/19201) is related, but no duplicate (because it's in German).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Urinsekt

It's a shorter compound word and means prehistoric (*Ur*) insect (*insekt*). A German name for *[Apterygota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apterygota)*.

However, *Urin* means urine and *Sekt* sparkling wine, so you could interpret it either

1. Ur-insekt (correct)
2. Urin-sekt (not so tasty)

And it even works if it's in plural

> Urinsekten

since *Sekten* means cults or sects.

---

There are actually quite a lot such words (they are [homographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph)) and I will list some more from Heinz Josef Weber's *Homographen-Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* (1996, [google books](https://books.google.de/books?id=ji7xjV-IymkC&lpg=PA16&ots=ho91jInUQ0&dq=komposita%20homographie&hl=de&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q=komposita%20homographie&f=false), pp. 16-17):

- *Kurtage* (broker's fee) / *Kur-tage* (days at a health resort)
- *Glieder-satz* (compound sentence) / *Glied-ersatz* (limb replacement)
- *Stau-becken* (reservoir, artificial lake) / *Staub-ecken* (dust corner)
- *Wach-stube* (guardroom) / *Wachs-tube* (collapsible tube containing wax)

Comment: "Not so tasty"[1]  citation needed

Comment: A good reason why Maklerkurtage is so rarely used that Google will ask you: Did you mean "Maklercourtage"? The non-Germanized spelling is predominant.

Comment: _Blumentopferde_ and _Klappfensterchen_ need to be added :-P ...