# Collisions in compound-noun space

Tags: compound

Are there are word collisions in German compound-noun space? This would mean two compound-nouns that are built from non-identical words, but when they are compounded, have no difference in spelling?

A pseudo-example, if the word "lächen" existed, and with capitalization to highlight the difference:

```
KauFlächen - chewing surface

KaufLächen - shopping laughter
```

Comment: Not a compound but _beinhalten_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - ah cool! And it can exist as a gerund (noun) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Beinhalten#German

Comment: There are even common jokes about _Blumentopferde_ or _Klappfensterchen_.

Comment: Some candidates found here (though the question is different): https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1705/35111

Comment: There are a few nice ones in the link. But the second interpretation of Kauflächen in the OP is not a German word. Blumento-Pferde do not exist, they are just a play of words.

Comment: "Laughter" would actually be "Lachen", not "Lächen" (or, depending on the context, "Gelächter").

Comment: Yes I know. I invented “Lächen” as an example.

Comment: *?Kauf-Flächen* "shopping floors"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German in general is known as extremely flexible in the compound-noun matter. 
Even when not accepted official as native word you can combine all nouns to whatever word you like and you are understood if it is not too strange.

So collisions are very likely simply because of the amount of possible combinations. There is no rule which would forbid these simply these collide. Some examples can be found here, but the search might be endless:

[Wörter mit ungünstiger Silbentrennung](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1705/35111)