# Darf oder soll im Fraktursatz, wenn man neuer Rechtschreibung geschrieben wird, »ſt« getrennt werden?

Tags: spelling, blackletter, hyphenation

Es dürfte allgemein bekannt sein, dass bis zur Rechtschreibreform des Jahres 1996 folgender Grundsatz galt:

> Trenne nie *st* (denn es tut den beiden weh).

Dies betraf unter Anderem Wörter wie *ko-sten* oder *er-sten.* Seit der Reform 1996 werden diese Wörter analog zu *Kon-ten, öf-ter, ern-ten* und *Werf-ten* an der Silbenfuge getrennt, also als *kos-ten* und *ers-ten.*

[Es wurde bereits die Frage gestellt, *woher* diese Trennungsregel kommt.](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7928) Um die bisher dort aufgeworfenen Argumente kurz zusammenzufassen: Die Regel stammt wahrscheinlich aus der Zeit der gebrochenen Schriften, denn sie galt nur für die Zeichenfolge *ſt,* nie für *st.* *ſt* war eine Zwangsligatur – doch das erklärt wenig, denn die Zwangsligatur *tz* wurde *kot-zen* getrennt, und selbst die Zwangsligatur *ck* wurde zu *lok-ken.* Ihren Sonderstatus teilt *ſt* also lediglich mit *(ſ)ch* (wobei im Sperrsatz *ſch* zu *ſ ch* wurde).

---

Nun ist diese Regel mit der Umstellung, wie bereits erwähnt, abgeschafft worden. Dennoch werden auch heute noch Texte aus vielerlei Gründen in Fraktur gesetzt und teilweise wird – wie zum Beispiel [auf dieser Seite](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/) – dabei sogar die neue Rechtschreibung verwendet, die sich vor Allem in *-ss* am Wortende zeigt. Die meisten 1996 geänderten Regeln machen hierbei wenig Probleme – ob man nun *ß* oder *ſs* am Morphemende setzt ist relativ gleich; manche Quellen behaupten gar, dass Ersteres aus Letzterem hervorgegangen sei. Doch die Frage nach der Worttrennung bei *ſt* ist etwas weniger eindeutig.

Sollte man *ſt* entgegen den amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln – die meines Wissens an keiner Stelle auf Fraktursatz hinweisen – **nicht** am Zeilenende trennen? Dafür spräche der Status als Zwangsligatur, die ja auch nicht im Sperrsatz getrennt wird. Auch dass Fraktursatz an keiner Stelle der amtlichen Regeln erwähnt wird, kann man so deuten, dass er schlicht nicht mitgedacht wurde und allein deswegen keine Regeln dafür formuliert wurden.

Oder sollte man *ſt* gemäß den derzeit gültigen amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln am Zeilenende **trennen?** Dafür spräche, dass es durchaus andere Kombinationen mit *ſ* gab, die am Zeilenende getrennt wurden, wie zum Beispiel *Floſ-ken* oder *Waſ-ſer;* sowie die bereits erwähnte Zwangsligatur *tz,* die ebenfalls getrennt wurde.

Diese Frage alleine ist wahrscheinlich, da rein meinungsbasiert, schließwürdig. Daher die Ergänzungsfrage: Was sagen dazu Rechtschreib- und Stilratgeber wie Duden oder andere? Empfehlen sie, im Fraktursatz *ko-ſten* oder *koſ-ten* zu trennen, wenn nach neuer Rechtschreibung geschrieben wird?

---

**Die Frage in Kurzfassung:**
Darf/soll, wenn nach neuer Rechtschreibung und im Fraktursatz geschrieben wird, die Buchstabenkombination *ſt* getrennt werden oder nicht?

Vor Allem: Was sagen Ratgeber wie Duden etc, so sie den Fraktursatz behandeln?

Comment: Es gibt Programme, die die Frakturschreibregeln für die Webdarstellung automatisch anwenden. Die machen es sich einfach - Zitat: "*kaufen Sie sich einen alten Duden*" (http://www.fontura.de/index.htm)

Comment: @tofro Aber mit dem Hinweis »kaufen Sie sich einen alten Duden« werde ich ja nur auf die Rechtschreibregeln von 1901 zurückverwiesen; dann müsste ich aber auch *müßte* schreiben, was ich nicht will. Die neue Rechtschreibung schlichtweg für den Fraktursatz als ungültig zu bezeichnen, ist mE keine Lösung.

Comment: Übrigens, man glaubt es kaum, aber: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/293/was-sind-die-genauen-regeln-zur-benutzung-des-buchstabens-ſ

Comment: Wer in Fraktur schreibt dokumentiert bereits, dass er sich nicht an die Konvention hält. Hoffen wir, dass er mit guten Gründen zu diesem Stilmittel greift - es kann ja kaum noch wer lesen. Dann sollte er auch so stilsicher sein selbst zu entscheiden, wie er trennt.

Comment: Ich würde es analog zu _ck_ behandeln: entweder _k-k_ und _s-t_ oder _-ck_ und _-ſt_, aber nie _c-k_ oder _ſ-t_. (_-ck_ finde ich furchtbar.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Offizielle Rechtschreibregeln

Nicht nur der Fraktursatz, sondern auch das lange *s* werden in den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln nicht erwähnt, im Gegenteil steht direkt am Anfang des Regelwerks:

> Die Schreibung des Deutschen beruht auf einer Buchstabenschrift.
>   Jeder Buchstabe existiert als Kleinbuchstabe und als Großbuchstabe
>   (Ausnahme ß):
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ä ö ü ß
>   A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z Ä Ö Ü

Demnach ist die Verwendung des langen *s* überhaupt nicht rechtschreibkonform.

Mit viel Wohlwollen (oder Wunschdenken) kann man sich höchstens auf den Standpunkt stellen, dass *ſ* eine andere Form von *s* ist und es orthografisch egal ist, ob man *ſ* oder *s* nutzt. Nach dieser Interpretation greifen alle Regeln, die *s* betreffen, auch für *ſ* und damit ist *ſt* trennbar.

#### Duden

Der Duden enthält einen Abschnitt zur Verwendung des langen *ſ* im Fraktursatz. Die dort empfohlenen Regeln sind im Wesentlichen die historischen angepasst auf die neue Rechtschreibung bzw. die Regeln der heyseschen *s*-Schreibung. In meiner Ausgabe wird die Trennung von *ſt* nicht erwähnt und es gibt auch kein Beispiel, wo zufällig ein trennbares *ſt* auf ein Zeilenende trifft (meine Ausgabe ist nicht die allerneueste, aber ich bezweifle, dass sich hieran etwas geändert hat).

Da es keine Sonderregel gibt, greifen also die normalen Regeln und *ſt* darf getrennt werden. Ein Verbot der Trennung von *ſt* widerspräche auch dem Tenor der *ſ*-Regeln, die eben Anpassungen an die neue Rechtschreibung enthalten.

#### Meine Meinung™

*(Da ich mich intensiv mit dem Thema beschäftigt habe, ist diese eventuell sogar etwas wert.)*

Den einzigen Grund, den ich sehe, das lange *s* im Fraktursatz zu verwenden, ist, dass man eine historische Wirkung erzielen möchte – die offizielle Rechtschreibung sieht das lange *s* sowieso nicht vor und modernen Lesegewohnheiten dient es auch nicht. Eine historische Wirkung passt aber nicht wirklich zur Verwendung einer aktuellen Rechtschreibung um der Aktualität willen. Andererseits sind viele Aspekte der neuen Rechtschreibung gar nicht brandneu, sondern existierten schon einmal: Zum Beispiel ist die *s*-Schreibung an Heyses Regeln angelehnt und ich habe auch schon *Schifffahrt* in offiziellen Dokumenten aus dem 19. Jahrhundert gesehen.

Kurzum: Wer das lange *s* und neue Rechtschreibung zusammen verwendet, handelt sowieso nach Gutdünken – was jetzt nicht unbedingt schlecht ist, da er sich sowieso auf hochspeziellem Terrain bewegt und im Hinblick auf die Anwendung entscheiden muss – und soll selbst entscheiden.

Ich persönlich halte das *ſt*-Trennverbot im Fraktursatz genauso unsinnig wie im Antiqua-Satz (Du hast die Gründe schon genannt) und würde es nur dann befolgen, wenn ich den Schriftsatz einer gewissen Zeit authentisch reproduzieren möchte – dann würde ich aber nicht die neue Rechtschreibung verwenden.

Comment: Ich sehe das ähnlich. Dass ſt nicht zu trennen ist, ist eine alte Rechtschreibregel. Dass ſt als Ligatur zu schreiben ist, wenn die Buchstaben zusammenstossen, eine Schriftsatzregel (aber eine andere). Wenn durch eine nun erlaubte Trennung s und t nicht mehr zusammentreffen, muss man auch keine Ligatur mehr setzen.

Answer (score 4):

Die Schriftart hat keinen Einfluss auf die Trennungsregeln. Ligaturen werden gesetzt, weil sie ästhetitisch ansprechender sind als es die beiden Buchstaben wären, wenn sie direkt aufeinander folgen. Sind sie getrennt, folgen sie nicht mehr direkt aufeinander, es besteht also kein Problem.

Comment: Wer das lange *s* nutzt, muss mehr ändern als nur die Schriftart.